How can Babel transpile a Node.js module polyfill (e.g. buffer) to ES5?
I would like to transpile JS code which uses the Node 'buffer' to pure ES5 so it can run on Duktape (with Webpack and Babel).
The code has been simplified in a test.js, which uses buffer and console:
import "core-js/stable"; // just in case it might help
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');

const buf1 = Buffer.alloc(10);

let a = 3;
console.log("BLAH");

webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// Provide code node modules in webpack 5+ (eg. path, stream, sys, timers, ...)
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //mode: 'development', // otherwise it is using long evals which duktape doesn't like
  mode: 'production',

  target: 'es5',

  entry: [
    'core-js/stable',
    './src/test.js'
  ],

  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
       
  plugins: [
    // polyfill the nodejs modules
    // use NodePolyfillPlugin instead of resolve.fallback(s) - both have been tried without success
    new NodePolyfillPlugin({
        onlyAliases: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
  ],
    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "src") ],
                use: ['babel-loader']
                
                // options in .babelrc
                // no targets -> scrictest environment => es5
            }
        ]
    },
    

    
  output: {
      
    filename: 'run-es5-sync-contacts.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    
    chunkFormat: false,
      
    // copy/past from webpack doc
    environment: {
            // The environment supports arrow functions ('() => { ... }').
            arrowFunction: false,
            // The environment supports async function and await ('async function () { await ... }').
            asyncFunction: false,
            // The environment supports BigInt as literal (123n).
            bigIntLiteral: false,
            // The environment supports const and let for variable declarations.
            const: false,
            // The environment supports destructuring ('{ a, b } = obj').
            destructuring: false,
            // The environment supports an async import() function to import EcmaScript modules.
            dynamicImport: false,
            // The environment supports an async import() when creating a worker, only for web targets at the moment.
            dynamicImportInWorker: false,
            // The environment supports 'for of' iteration ('for (const x of array) { ... }').
            forOf: false,
            // The environment supports 'globalThis'.
            globalThis: false,
            // The environment supports ECMAScript Module syntax to import ECMAScript modules (import ... from '...').
            module: false,
            // The environment supports optional chaining ('obj?.a' or 'obj?.()').
            optionalChaining: false,
            // The environment supports template literals.
            templateLiteral: false,
        },
  },

    performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 2048000,
            maxAssetSize: 2048000
    },
    
};

.babelrc ("targets" is explicitly omitted so it uses the strictest JavaScript standard: ES5):
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "debug": true,
        "corejs": { "version": 3, "proposals": true },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "forceAllTransforms": true, // for stricter non-standard environment: duktape
        "ignoreBrowserslistConfig": true
    }]
  ]
}

The code is properly transpiled, yet the final output includes the code coming from nodes_modules/buffer/index.js which uses the JS keywords let and const, and therefore fails when executing it using duktape (as duktape does apparently not support let and const).
dist/run-es5-sync-contacts.js still somewhere includes the lines from buffer/index.js:
...
Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow = function (size) {
  return allocUnsafe(size)
}

function fromString (string, encoding) {
  if (typeof encoding !== 'string' || encoding === '') {
    encoding = 'utf8'
  }

  if (!Buffer.isEncoding(encoding)) {
    throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding)
  }

  const length = byteLength(string, encoding) | 0
  let buf = createBuffer(length)

  const actual = buf.write(string, encoding)

  if (actual !== length) {
    // Writing a hex string, for example, that contains invalid characters will
    // cause everything after the first invalid character to be ignored. (e.g.
    // 'abxxcd' will be treated as 'ab')
    buf = buf.slice(0, actual)
  }

  return buf
}
...

Does anyone has an idea how to tell Babel to transpile the code imported through NodePolyfillPlugin (or directly specified with resolve.fallback) to a strict 'es5' target?
I would expect that output.environment does the trick, yet not for the modules polyfilled through NodePolyfillPlugin nor resolve.fallback.
I've looked through all documentation, searched for similar problems, tried many combinations, the final code still use let keywords.
Using let directly in test.js, is properly transpiled.
Tried setting resolve.fallback instead of using NodePolyfillPlugin, same result.
With the provided code, console is expected to be missing.
